# How do you hide a div that has a combination of id, class, and name together?

Tags: css

I've got a div that has `id="idname" name="specificname" and class="randomclass"` The problem is that the id and class are used in multiple instances and the name variable is the only unique part of that combination. How do you declare that in css to only affect that one div?

Comment: Well… you shouldn’t have IDs that are used across multiple elements.

Comment: When using a third party application and having to style on top of it its a terrible situation. This allows for you to edit things without affecting the source code.

Answer (score -2):

Using css you would put in this entry.

```
div.randomclass[name="specificname"][id="idname"] {
  display: none;
}
```

replace display: none with whatever styling your looking at using and it will work out without affecting any other divs with that name or class.